# How to get the Text value of a control (Label) by referring to it using its string Name?

Tags: c#, winforms

On my form I have a label with `Name = "PART1"`.

In that label `Text = "Company A"`.

What is the right way to get the result "`Company A`" by referring to the label using the string "`PART1`".

There are many labels on the form and I want to collect what has been entered in each label using:

```
for ( i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) 
{
    result = GetTheValue("PART" + i.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```cs
private string GetTheValue(string name)
{
    return this.Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == name)?.Text;
}
```

Note that `this` is the Form which holds the labels. If your labels are placed in some container (like a Panel) you need to replace `this` with the corresponding container (e.g. `panel1`)